# IE9 standards mode meta tag

Tags: asp.net, html, meta-tags

I use jquery ui tabs and it didnt work on IE9 normaly for me.

How can i fix it ?

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
```

ie9 gives error :

```
HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=EmulateIE7') ignored because document mode is already finalized.
```

Comment: Where does this error display?  Does it show up like a javascript error, or is it a popup dialog?

Comment: its a warning , i cant this warning on ie8 standards, but i got this warning on ie9 standards mode.I can see it on developer tools

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that you have a second `X-UA-Compatible` tag further down the page.

Comment: It's worth noting that the content of the javascript error seems unrelated to your meta tag. You've got "ie-edge" in your markup, but the error is about "IE=EmulateIE7"; surely there are two tags.

Comment: @GabrielIsenberg I think that's the whole point. "document mode already finalized" because it has already been set to `edge` by the first meta element. On the other hand, the question also mentions jquery and asp.net, which have no bearing on the problem as stated, so maybe there's more to this than we know. Or maybe the OP has two problems mixed up.

Comment: @MrLister Definitely not enough information to go on at the moment :)

Comment: you are right guys , i also use htmleditor and its js code generate auto meta tag for ie7 :) thx

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use IE9 without Quirks mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```